# Debugging PyQt4 using a core file

Tags: python, gdb, segmentation-fault, pyqt4

I have a bug in my python script that is using PyQt4 that causes a segmentation fault.
I could not find the bug using pdb, so now I wanna try it with gdb.
The core file is written and when I open it and type `where`, I just get memory addresses and only question marks as function names.
I already installed the python-qt4-dbg package on Ubuntu but that did not help.

Is there any additional parameter I have to pass to gdb to make the function names appear?

Cheers,

Manuel

Comment: That seems odd. Nothing in python should give a seg fault. They should always just be exceptions.

Comment: Dhaivat: there are numerous bugs in Qt and PyQt that will cause segmentation faults. There are also many ways to cause segfaults via pyqt which are not considered bugs by the pyqt devs.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you will also need at least libqt4-dbg and python-dbg, maybe a few others..

Comment: Wow, really? libqt4-dbg is 500MB

Comment: So it is! I've no idea why it is so big, but since python-qt4 uses libqt4, you do need libqt4-dbg to get a proper trace.